# angular - guards does not wait for parent resolvers to complete

Tags: angular, observable, angular-router, angular-router-guards, angular-resolver

My router is like this

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  resolve: {
    user: UserResolver,
  },
  children: [{
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [HomeGuard],
    component: HomeComponent,
  }, {
    ...otherRoutes,
  }],
}];
```

In order to authorize access, the `HomeGuard` needs a data that is in the data retrieved by the `UserResolver`. The problem is that `HomeGuard` does not wait for `UserResolver` to be completed.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<User> {
    return this.api.getUser().pipe(
      delay(1000), // simulates the api call duration
      map((user: User) => {
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

In other stackoverflow posts, people claim that the resolver resolves object before navigating, but does it mean guards wait for parents resolvers to be completed?

EDIT.
Is it okay to use a guard as resolver?

Answer (score 3):

According to angular documentation.

> When both guard and resolvers are specified, the resolvers are not executed until all guards have run and succeeded.

And please do check the example explained also in the [angular documentation.](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#usage-notes)